# Subprocess Call in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.4

Hey guys I have a pretty simple code.

```
subprocess.call(dirIFLO+'IFLO.exe')
```

Where dirIFLO is just a folder above the current working directory
This code is suppose to run IFLO.exe while my code waits. The program does start but somehow it does not manage to get the files they were suppose to in the same directory it is. If I manually open it I get it working just fine.

Comment: You are asking it to run /home/me/IFLO.exe (for example) but you might well be in /home/me/python, so my guess is, that it's looking for the data in /home/me/python. Is there a command line option to tell IFLO.exe where to look for the data? If so add that to the subprocess.call statement.

Comment: I think that's it. But I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: What command line options are available for IFLO.exe? (IFLO.exe -? or IFLO.exe -help) might give you a clue

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work by accessing the subdirectory and calling the program instead of opening the subroutine straight from the working directory.

```
w = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(dirIFLO[:-2])
subprocess.call('IFLO.exe')
os.chdir(w)
```

Comment: Please don't operate on paths as if they where just strings, there is the `os.path` module with functions to *safely* manipulate paths. And `os.chdir()` is ”evil” as it changes global state and you easily might end up with a current working directory which other parts of the program don't expect.  `subprocess.Popen` has a `cwd` keyword argument and `subprocess.call()` can take all arguments that `Popen` knows about.  So it's a one liner: `subprocess.call(['IFLO.exe'], cwd=dirIFLO)`.